# javascript prototype access options from init - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, plugins

In a javascript prototype, is it possible for methods to access the properties of other methods, for eg: how to make options available to the open method?

```
function Plugin(element, options) {
    Modal = this;
    Modal.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    Modal._defaults = defaults;
    Modal.init(Modal.element, Modal.options);
}


Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function(element, options) {
        console.log(options);
    },
    open: function() {
        //Does this function have access to options?
        //how to modify so that 'open' function has access to options
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

However, you already put them in `this`, so you can write `this.options`.

Answer (score 1):

store it as this._options in the first method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Modal` is an implicit global, which I suspect was not intentional. Use `var` to limit it to the local scope.

```
function Plugin(element, options) {
    var Modal = this;
    Modal.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    Modal._defaults = defaults;
    Modal.init(Modal.element, Modal.options);
}
```

Secondly, since `options` has been added as a property of the instance by the constructor, you can access it in the prototype method:

```
open: function() {
    console.log(options);
}
```